# Create page on text overflow Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am making a book reader app, similar to ibook, but I am having a problem where I am using a page view, and would like to make it so that the pages are made depending on the size of the text, so that they don't overflow, and continue seamlessly to the next created page, is that possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible - see `TextPainter` class documentation - it has methods to measure the text (for example `getBoxesForSelection` and some other `get*` methods)

Comment: Does it work with page view builder fine, or does it have to be a different type?

Comment: you can use it with `PageView`, no problem

Comment: I thank u for answering, I will try to learn how to use it, if u do have any sites with examples on how  **TextPainter** is used, in order for me to grasp it, it will be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: no, i dont know any sites